# Find Determinant/or Row Reduce parameter dependent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the determinant of a band diagonal matrix that has a parameter, $\kappa$,  in some of the entries. Some entries are just numerical ones, others ($\kappa$ X number), while others are ($\kappa$ + number). I have been told that they way to solve for $\kappa$ is to find the determinant of the this matrix and then find values of $\kappa$ that make the determinant zero.

The main issue I'm having is that when my matrix becomes large the determinant just results to zero,and in other cases to calculation overflow. (I'm trying to work out all the bugs in the code, so det =0, might be some error I'm making, but the overflow error is not avoidable).

I have already tried an `LUDecomposition` on the matrix, and that seems to take forever, I don't have a problem waiting, but working out the scaling, it seemed like I would have to wait a couple of days for a 500X500 matrix, and my real problem might have to be done on a 1000X1000 matrix.

I was also thinking that maybe I could somehow get the matrix into an upper triangular form and then just multiply the diagonal elements. For this I tried using *Mathematica's* `RowReduce` command, but for some weird reason that just results in the identity matrix. I thought that `RowReduce` might give me an upper triangular matrix with $f(\kappa)$ on the diagonal, and I could just multiply the diagonal elements and get a polynomial for $\kappa$ and solve.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I'm not really sure how to put up my code, or the matrix for that matter. That is the thing that would probably help you guys the most. If there is a way for me to put up the matrix please let me know.

Thanks again.

EDIT- A matrix that gives you guys some idea of my matrix.

```
t2 = {{-892.33, 973.21, 44.306 + \[Kappa], -81.103,0}, 
 {446.12, -557.94, 0, -682.54, -314.89}, 
 {0,893.37, -506.68*\ [Kappa],-391.457, 0}, {0, 429.78, 0, -210.47, 
 342.85}, {278.32*\[Kappa], 0, 963.41, 217.71, -342.68 + \[Kappa]}}
```

**2nd-EDIT**
Although I do not fully understand what Jens' code is doing I did try it on my real matrix. The result is

```
In[193]:= f[\[Kappa]_?NumericQ] := 
 Min[Diagonal[SingularValueDecomposition[mat][[2]]]]
In[194]:= Plot[f[\[Kappa]], {\[Kappa], 0, 2}]
```

Well being a noob the site won't let me upload an image, but it basically looks like there should be roots around $\kappa$ = .1, .2, .4,.4, .6.

So I tried to find the root using

```
In[196]:= FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}]
```

And then I get a bunch of error messages.

```
During evaluation of In[196]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval:
Input value {-0.173686} lies outside the range of data 
in the interpolating function.Extrapolation will be used. >>

During evaluation of In[196]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval: 
Input value {-0.173686} lies outside the range of data in the 
interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

During evaluation of In[196]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval: 
Input value {-0.173686} lies outside the range of data 
in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

 During evaluation of In[196]:= General::stop: Further output of   
 InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

 Out[196]= {x -> -3.28829*10^-13}
```

So I figured that if root-finder couldn't do it, I'd just try it by hand, i.e. just look at the plot and keep narrowing down the point where f($\kappa$) =0, so I tried to evaluate

```
 In[190]:= f[.2]
```

which was taking forever considering that this command

```
In[193]:= f[\[Kappa]_?NumericQ] := 
Min[Diagonal[SingularValueDecomposition[mat][[2]]]]
```

and the plot command both took less than an second. I'm very confused.

**3rd Edit**
I think I can post a picture now. So I will include my plot for `f[x]`. This might make it easier to figure out what is going wrong with root-finder. I'm thinking its the multiple roots.

[image]

**4th Edit**
Hi All, Happy almost 4th of July,

There is some good news and some bad news about the code thus far. The good news is that it seems to be working fine for larger grid sizes. I haven't cranked it up too much b/c my computer can't really handle it. The bad news is that I'm getting complex solutions. I know that the physical problem I am dealing with should not have complex solutions. Therefore when I was implementing the code by finding det(mat($\kappa$)= 0 , and solving the resulting polynomial for the roots I was using `Solve[d1 == \[Kappa], Reals]`, where `d1 = Det[mat]`. This allowed me to only examine the real roots. However using the code

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := Last[SingularValueList[mat /. \[Kappa] -> x]]
Plot[g[x], {x, .5, 2/3}]
```

Gives me the following plot

[image: SVD-updatedPlot]

and then I try `FindRoot[g[x], {x, .58, .55, .6}]`.  Which results in `{x -> 0.580341}`, and the following error message

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance    
specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a 
sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 
MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>
```

Which I looked up and is supposed to mean that root finder cannot find real roots. So my first question is: what does `{x -> 0.506739}`, mean if *Mathematica* couldn't find real roots?

I've also tried to increase the `AccracyGoal` and `WorkingPresicion` with this

```
FindRoot[g[x], {x, .58, .55, .6}, AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision,     
WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Which results in a similar error.

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance 
specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a 
sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 20.` 
digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>
```

So I'm quite lost as to where to go now. I've gone through my code and made sure that I put everything in fractional form, i.e. 1/2 instead of .5 since I know that can reduce precision, and make *Mathematica* angry.

As an aside, I wanted to throw another question out there. From the plot we can see that there are many roots present. And that there will be even more when I make the grid-size larger. I've already restricted the values for $\kappa$ to what is physically possible (in the Plot command), but that stills results in 10 -20 roots. Is there any other way to know which root is the real physics answer?

**5th Edit**
New plot with Jens' suggestion used in code.

[image: SVD-plot3]

Now there are also no errors when I try the `FindRoot` command.

**6th Edit,So this strange...or is it?** If I understand the procedure that we have worked out thus far, the plots that I created above tell me "how singular" my matrix is as a function of my parameter $\kappa$. Thus I would probably like my y-axis to be really small, and so I am telling `SingularValueList` to only give me the last entry since that should be the smallest singular value, and also why I'm using the tolerance function,so that the smallest value do not get ignored. One question is, why use tolerance if were are already looking at the smallest singular value?
The other problem, the strange part, is that when I find a $\kappa$ using `SVL`, and root finding command, then write $\kappa = .508...$, and then `Det[mat]`, I get something like 2.14^113, and 1.678^109, for another root. Is that right? Is this essentially as close to zero as we can get the determinant? Or am I missing something huge. Is it that I am using the wrong root. Is there one that can give me Det = .0000001 or even smaller? I guess its not all bad news, this smalleness of the Det could help me figure out which is the true root. Anyways just throwing some thoughts/questions out there. Thanks again to all who respond. This problem is starting to drive me crazy but I guess that research.

Comment: Should it be `FindRoot[f[\[Kappa]],{\[Kappa],.5}]`? There was an `x`. Could this have generated the error messages?

Comment: @nightowl, I just checked with $\kappa$ instead of "x" it did not make a difference. I didn't think it would since I defined the function "f" it should have been able to take any variable as it input. Thanks for help, at least that part is troubleshot.

Comment: Are you sure kappa has finite roots? `Plot[Det[t2], {\[Kappa], -10, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]` (or `Solve[Det[t2] == 0, \[Kappa]]`)

Comment: Finding the determinant of a symbolic matrix is very, very slow, and it gets bad fast. On my machine, I cap out at $11\times 11$ matrices (which take 4 secs) before _Mathematica_ begins to chew up a lot of memory. Since you have a numerical matrix, $M$ plus a symbolic matrix of a single variable, $\kappa A$, it may be worthwhile to see if you can recast $A$ as a rank-1 or rank-l ($l\le n$) update. Then you can use the [matrix determinant lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). As this is non-trivial, I opted to just comment instead of providing an answer.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure if I can rewrite my problem like this, since there are terms like $\kappa$a(1,1) etc, but this is certainly something I will look into.

Comment: @TomD, Yes there should be finite roots, as I'm really try to reproduce research. Also I did get finite roots for a small version of my problem. Making the problem much larger is where the trouble starts.

Comment: Your example matrix does not appear as if it can be rewritten that way. But, it may be separable into multiple updates. That said, it isn't trivial, and I don't know if it can be done automatically, or a case-by-case analysis is required. I think the latter is more likely. If you can make use of it, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Again a stab in the dark: in your Edit 4, the jumps indicate that some of the small singular values are thrown away occasionally and then picked up again. You could try replacing `SingularValueList[m]` by `SingularValueList[m, Tolerance -> 0]` which will ensure that all singular values are kept.

Comment: @Jens, WOW. I officially think you are a Mathematica wizard. Sorry to have bothered you about this again, it seems like I really need a better understanding of  what the `SingularValueList` command does and what SVD does in general. I will have to present these results to my advisor so knowing exactly what my code does will be very important. But more importantly I would really like to know what my code is doing. If you have any suggestions about where to learn about this material, I would be happy to know. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the remaining problems are related to Mathematica, but to the setup of your matrix problem. I can't think of anything to say about that, except that it doesn't sound numerically stable. Many matrix decomposition methods attempt to renormalize the rows and/or columns before doing the decomposition, whereas that may not be possible for the determinant calculation. That could explain the difference in the results.

Comment: @Jens, I did not mean to get to far off topic, since this is a Mathematica related forum. I guess my main Mathematica related question that remains is with the `SingularValueList` command? As I was saying in "6th-Edit" I'm still a little stuck about how to interpret the results plot. Other than that I guess you are saying that `Det[mat]` should be zero, because we are using a singular value, but it is not b/c Mathematica is calculating the Det differently than it calculated the singular values. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I do believe I have the problem of my initial matrix being close to singular. How can I get the second to last singular value instead of the very last. I've tried `SingularValueList[mat /. \[Kappa] -> x,-2]]]`, but I don't think it is working.

Answer (score 10):

Not knowing anything else about the matrix, I can only suggest another alternative to the determinant (which sounds like it's prohibitively time-consuming).

If `m` is your matrix, try to find a root (or minimum) of

```
Min@Diagonal@SingularValueDecomposition[m][[2]]
```

instead. Unfortunately, `SingularValueDecomposition` is also very time consuming, but as I said, I don't know your matrix and therefore you may be lucky and it works. The lowest singular value will become zero when the matrix is singular.

**Simplification:** The second part `[[2]]` of `SingularValueDecomposition` is a square diagonal matrix, and by applying `Diagonal` to it I extract the one-dimensional list of singular values. This isn't really necessary since we don't need the other parts of `SingularValueDecomposition`. If all you want is the list of singular values, you should use

```
Last@SingularValueList[m]
```

**Edit**

No matter what method you end up choosing to test for the singularity of the matrix, you should probably *not* do it symbolically. That is, you have to define a "merit" function with your parameter $\kappa$ as a numerical variable:

Here is a crude example of a matrix and the corresponding function `f`:

```
m = {{0.7407182168539275`, 0.24672805625057825`, 
   0.8493016773864293`}, {0.06662628477504584`, 0.3469746999275358`, 
   0.2741493334768361`}, {0.07058419213858214`, 0.9556414582722623`, 
   0.7252123775090984`}};

f[κ_?NumericQ] := 
 Last[SingularValueList[m + DiagonalMatrix[{κ, 0, 0}]]]
```

**Edit 2: Explanation**

The pattern `f[κ_?NumericQ]` insures that the function will return a value *only* if it is called with a numerical argument `κ`. Any minimization or root finding routine will by default attempt to simplify `f[κ]` symbolically, but since `f` is defined *only* for numerical arguments that attempt will fail. This is good because the automatic evaluator then chooses a purely numerical method, which in our case is faster.

The `SetDelayed` `:=` in the function definition means that the evaluation on the right-hand side (i.e., the singular-value decomposition or any other decomposition you may choose) will *only* be performed at the time when the function is called with a numerical parameter `κ`. At that point, if everything else in the matrix is numerical, the entire matrix is a numerical matrix and the result will not involve anything symbolic.

Finally, the reason I take only the `Last` part of the `SingularValueList` is that it is automatically the smallest. The smallest singular value is the one that first hits zero when a matrix becomes singular. That it the point of zero determinant we're looking for.

There are complications when you work with matrices that are *already* close to being numerically singular, because in that case you'll have to decide *how close* to singular you want the matrix to get as you vary the parameter. In those cases one may have to look at the next higher singular values.

Here I plot the example `f`, which is now an "indicator" of how singular the matrix is:

```
Plot[f[κ], {κ, 0, 2}]
```

[image: root]

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 1}]

(* ==> {x -> 1.78179} *)
```

Applying this to **your example**:

```
f[κ_?NumericQ] := 
 Last[
   SingularValueList[{{-892.33`, 973.21`, 
       44.306` + κ, -81.103`, 0}, {446.12`, -557.94`, 
       0, -682.54`, -314.89`}, {0, 
       893.37`, -506.68` κ, -391.457`, 0}, {0, 429.78`, 
       0, -210.47`, 342.85`}, {278.32` κ, 0, 963.41`, 
       217.71`, -342.68` + κ}}]]
```

We can make a plot and realize that there won't likely be a zero for real values
`κ`, but in the complex plane things look more promising:

```
Plot[Abs[f[κ - 2 I]], {κ, -20, 20}]
```

[image: complex]

Here I've subtracted an imaginary part from the real `κ`, and the curve seems to dip sharply down to close to zero. So let's try the following minimization:

```
sol = FindMinimum[Abs[f[x + I y]], {{x, -1}, {y, -2}}]
```

> `FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size...`
>
> `{1.89011*10^-6, {x -> -0.777723, y -> -2.07495}}`

So there's still some work to do to get rid of the warning message, but in principle we got somewhere.

**Edit 3**

In order to make a *pre-existing* matrix `mat` (containing a parameter `κ`) into a function that you can use for root finding etc., you have to watch out for the difference between the global variable `κ` and the pattern instance `κ` that is passed to the function in place of the "dummy variable" in the pattern `f[κ_?NumericQ]`.

The dummy variable could have equally well been named `x_` or `b_`, so how do we make sure that it gets substituted into the matrix wherever the global variable `κ` appears?

Here is a way to do that. Assume the matrix is externally given as

```
Clear[κ]; mat = {{-892.33`, 973.21`, 44.306` + κ, -81.103`, 
    0}, {446.12`, -557.94`, 0, -682.54`, -314.89`}, {0, 
    893.37`, -506.68` κ, -391.457`, 0}, {0, 429.78`, 
    0, -210.47`, 342.85`}, {278.32` κ, 0, 963.41`, 
    217.71`, -342.68` + κ}};
```

Then change your function definition to

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Last[SingularValueList[mat /. κ -> x]]
```

What this does is to replace the global `κ` (which you must make sure is **unassigned**, hence the `Clear` for safety) by the value of the dummy variable in the function. I have to change its name to something other than `κ`, so I chose `x`.

**Edit 4**

To capture what I said in some additional comments: if you *do* decide to use the lowest singular value as a merit function for further root finding or minimization, as a function of the parameter `κ`, then you may run into the problem that `SingularValueList` will *omit* the lowest singular values if they are too small relative to the *largest* singular value. This can lead to jumps if you plot the lowest singular value versus `κ`, because you aren't tracking the same singular value at all times. To insure that no singular values are omitted, one has to use

```
SingularValueList[m, Tolerance -> 0]
```

I can't answer the question of whether this is physically the best procedure, because I don't know what the physical problem is.

A very good mathematical discussion of the singular value decomposition is in [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) on page 59.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thank you so much for the your response. I will definitely have to take a look at into the singular value decomposition idea. I think I follow most of what you did, but I'm not sure if I can apply this to my matrix. I should have done this earlier, but I created a fake matrix (I added it under my original post), which I believe gives a clearer idea of what I am dealing with. I'm not really sure I could use this SVDecomp trick with that matrix. Sorry to be a bother but could you please provide further instruction. You've hit upon the main issue, getting around doing it symbolically.

Comment: OK, so I actually understand *[Diagonal[
   SingularValueDecomposition[
     m + DiagonalMatrix[{κ, 0, 0}]][[2]]]]* that part of your code. You are creating a matrix with ($\kappa$ + number) at the (1,1) entry, and then preforming a SVD on that matrix. The *[[2]]]* allows you to call the second part of the SVD output, and *Diagonal* asks for the diagonal elements of the matrix that has all of the singular values. But I am still confused about *f[κ_?NumericQ] := 
 Min[*. What does calling *Min* do? Also, I've never seen a function defined like this *f[κ_?NumericQ] :=*. Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried to add some more discussion - hope this helps with your actual matrix...

Comment: Thank you very much Jens, I did not expect this much detail, you are wonderful. I need sometime to figure out why the *Min* or *Last* command needs to be called. And I also need to figure out why this technique seems to be failing in my real problem (details in my 2nd edit) , but I do very much appreciate the help.

Comment: I forgot to ask one important thing, and that is about the SVD. It seems to be that SVD returns something symbolic, and then only by creating a function that accepts numerically inputs are we making that numeric "merit function" you mentioned. Am I getting that right? The way I see it is that by plotting[f[x]]from 0 to 2, we are letting f[x] take numbers from 0 to 2 as numeric input and then it creates the plot you showed. I guess the crux of my question is that if SVD is symbolic then what is the real gain in using this than just doing Det[matrix]?

Comment: Sorry about all of these comments. I just wanted to clarify the last one. I really want to be able to find a way to take $\kappa$ out of the matrix,and then evaluate the determinant, b/c I figure that shouldn't take any time at all. But of course $\kappa$ is the most important piece, so not sure how  I can go about this. Also any ideas about that RowReduce issue I'm having.

Comment: You guys realize that `SingularValueList[]` is available if only the singular values are needed, right? No need for that `Diagonal[SingularValueDecomposition[(* matrix *))][[2]]]` construction if you've no use for the accompanying unitary matrices...

Comment: @J.M. Ah yes. I did the whole thing from memory... I should change the code to avoid having to explain so much. I think I may have been thinking back to the old LAPACK routines I used a lot...

Comment: Also, if you use `SingularValueList[]`, the singular values are already nicely sorted in non-increasing order, so you can use `Last[]` instead of `Min[]`. One might want to mind the `Tolerance` option if needed...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I had already changed that - or so I thought. I was in a hurry and forgot to change it in the last example...

Comment: @AshikIdrisy Re: your question what the advantage over determinants is: that indeed depends on the structure of the matrix. For a banded matrix the determinant may be fast enough to calculate. But in general for a dense matrix it isn't.

Comment: @J.M. Hello, Thanks so much for your input. I've tried using `g[\[Kappa]_?NumericQ] := Last[SingularValueList[mat]]` and then plotting the results it looks mostly the same.Then I'm using `FindRoot[g[x], {x, .5}]`. No errors this time its's still running after one whole Colbert Repor, and used up about 1.5 is GB of RAM, so yeah.

Comment: @AshikIdrisy Oh, I see another problem - I got sidetracked, but now I notice that you put the matrix into the function the wrong way. I'll add that to the answer... Try `g[\[Kappa]_?NumericQ] := mat` and you'll see that the parameter isn't substituted correctly!

Comment: @Jens, Thanks so much for catching my error. So now I have tried `g[x_?NumericQ] := Last[SingularValueList[mat /. \[Kappa] -> x]]`, and then `FindRoot[g[x], {x, .6}]` and this results in `{x -> 0.580403}`. Which was a result from det(A($\kappa$))=0. So I think all is well. Now to try bigger grid-sizes and see what happens. Thanks everyone, and special thanks to  Jens.

Answer (score 6):

You can compute the determinant by interpolation, as below.

```
In[149]:= 
t2 = {{-892.33, 973.21, 44.306 + kappa, -81.103, 0}, {446.12, -557.94,
     0, -682.54, -314.89}, {0, 893.37, -506.68*kappa, -391.457, 
    0}, {0, 429.78, 0, -210.47, 342.85}, {278.32*kappa, 0, 963.41, 
    217.71, -342.68 + kappa}};

In[151]:= vals = Table[Det[t2], {kappa, 1, Length[t2] + 1}];

In[153]:= InterpolatingPolynomial[vals, kappa] // Expand

Out[153]= -2.05175*10^14 - 6.49939*10^13 kappa - 
 4.17848*10^13 kappa^2 + 1.8125 kappa^3 - 0.273438 kappa^4 + 
 0.015625 kappa^5
```

A big problem is that you are very likely to run into issues with numeric stability. If, as Jens suggests, you are trying to find a value of kappa for which the matrix becomes singular, his SVD approach looks to be more viable than working with the determinant.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your response and for providing code. If I understand you're method you are calculating the determinant for values of $\kappa$ ranging form 1 to (length of the matrix+1). What is the reasoning for picking these bounds? I was planning on trying something like this myself, and now I have the code for it, thanks again. I don't know a lot about numeric stability, so I'm not quite sure what kind of problems to expect there. I'm sure these are problems I would like to avoid, but using SVD does take a while since things are still being done symbolically. Thanks.

Comment: Since kappa only appears linearly in the amtrix, we know the det is a polynomial in kappa of degree at most the dimension of the matrix. That accounts for the number of values I used. As for what values to pick, probably it would be numerically better to center them around the origin. But I doubt anything will be sufficient to gain numerically a nice expression, e.g. something you could extract accurate roots from (let alone take home to meet your parents). I think for the SVD you want to only compute it when kappa is given actual numeric values. Jens used this in his FindMinimum method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed Jens' method would have been perfect, the main issue I'm running into that is that the root finder is failing. Also, I don't get the idea that SVD only computes when numerical values are passed to it. Doesn't mathematica first have to create a symbolic function from SVD using the input matrix with its $\kappa$ entries? There is something that I'm definitely missing since `f[κ_?NumericQ] := 
 Last[SingularValueList[m + DiagonalMatrix[{κ, 0, 0}]]]` runs in 1 sec, but `f[.2]` or `SVD[matrix]`,seems to take forever. Thanks again.

Comment: See Jens' most recent edit. It should address your speed concern.

Comment: So I tried this interpolation method,and you were spot on about the numerical instability, the roots I was getting were very far off from the expected value. Thanks for the help.